# Bluemix Account error: BXNUI0301E

Tags: ibm-cloud, account

ES:
No se han podido recuperar las organizaciones al intentar obtener información sobre uso. Vuelva a intentarlo más tarde. Consulte los temas sobre resolución de problemas de la documentación de IBM Bluemix para comprobar el estado del servicio, revisar la información

EN:
"No fetch organizations when trying to obtain information on use. Try it again later. See topics on troubleshooting documentation IBM bluemix to check the service status, review the information"

---

This error occurs when trying to access my account information (right side bar) to check usage on different geographies and organizations.

Comment: Could you provide more details on what you were trying to do when receiving the error above?

Comment: Added. Hope it is enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After changing Browser language to English problem disappeared.